# Python: How to write for every x use x?

Tags: python

```
#python

list="""a 1 2 3 4 5
b 1 2 3 4 5
c 1 2 3 4 5 """


a=list.split('\n')
if a[0][0]==a:
    do something
if a[1][0]==b:
    do something
if a[2][0]==c:
    do something
```

is there an automated way for python to read the first part of each line? instead of doing the above? I'm trying to use the first str char on each line as a way for python to recognize the next action to take.

Comment: Thanks sashkello slicing helped!

Comment: Don't name a variable `list`. *Especially* one that's not a list.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a dictionary and map `'a'`,`'b'`,`'c'` to some functions.:

```
def func1(): print "func1"

def func2(): print "func2"

def func3(): print "func3"

dic={"a":func1,"b":func2,"c":func3}

lis="""a 1 2 3 4 5
b 1 2 3 4 5
c 1 2 3 4 5 """

for item in lis.splitlines():
    dic[item[0]]()
```

**output:**

```
func1
func2
func3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could of course use a hash to map names to actions:

```
actions = { "a": do_a, "b": do_b, "c": do c }

for l in list.splitlines():
  here = l[0]
  if here in actions:
    actions[here]()
```

Answer (score -2):

`map(lambda xs: if xs[0] == a: dosomething, list.split('\n'))` might be what you are looking for.